# Is there any Dependency Injection solution for nodejs similar to angular injector

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection

Angular injector is awesome and it would be great to find to use the same concept in the backend. Is there something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just released [Electrolyte](https://github.com/jaredhanson/electrolyte), which follows a similar pattern, but geared toward Node.js applications.

Comment: It's good to know it. node-di sas my option. I'll check it out. Thanks